# User in voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord music bot, but `message.member.voice.channel` always returns null. I have seen many other questions like that on stackoverflow, but none of them seem to help me. Here's the code:

```
     function play(message, args) {
        const VoiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        console.log(VoiceChannel);
        if(!VoiceChannel) message.reply('You need to be in a voice channel');
        if(!args.length) message.reply('You need to specify song name');
    }
    /*............................................................................*/
if(command === 'play'){
    play(message, args);
}
```

(args.length works as it should, unlike VoiceChannel)

Comment: Maybe you have missing intent ? You can post the intents here.

Comment: const { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError, User, Channel, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the current intents are GUILDS and GUILD_MESSAGES the problem must be coming from the missing GUILD_VOICE_STATES intent. Make sure to include it in the intents array and it should fix your problem.